# Dependent test cases in TestNG Retry using RetryAnalyzer

Tags: testng

My test class is designed in such a way that the current test case is dependent on the previous test case. I have to implement a retry mechanism for it. I tried it using - AnnotationTransformer and RetryAnalyzer. The problem I am facing is as soon as a test case is failed, it will be immediately re-executed. The @AfterClass method and the dependent methods are not executed because of which the retry of the test case would not ever pass. eg suppose the test class is:

```
public class Gate{
@test
public void testCase1()
{
Login;
create new user;
logout;
}
@test
public void testCase2(dependsOnMethods = { "testCase1" }, enabled = true)
{
login with new user;
verify login;   
}
}
```

If my test case is failing to verify the login step. I want it to execute the @AfterClass method first so that the entire data is trashed and everything starts from scratch.

Please suggest me how to go ahead with this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [TestListeners](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners) for such a requirement. Here is an example -

```
import org.testng.ITestContext ;        
import org.testng.ITestListener ;       
import org.testng.ITestResult ;     

public class ListenerTest implements ITestListener                      
{

 @Override      
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {                 
       //flush the data here                    
    }
}
```

And then add this listener in your testng xml file -

```
<listener class-name="//classpath to ListenerTest class" />
```

**EDIT -**

This is probably not what you want. First of all if you want to execute your flush method, you should use `@AfterMethod` instead of `@AfterClass`. The latter will be executed *after* all your test methods in a class are executed including any dependent methods. Suppose you have `@BeforeClass`, `@BeforeMethod`, `@AfterMethod`, `@AfterClass`, then the order of the execution TestNG will follow along with Retry is(assuming your test case fails and retry count is 1) -

1) @BeforeClass

2) @BeforeMethod

3) @Test (testCase1)

4) Retry method (in your RetryAnalyzer implementation)

5) @AfterMethod

6) @BeforeMethod

7) @Test (testCase1)

9) @AfterMethod

10) Any Test Listener like the one mentioned above

11) @BeforeMethod

12) @Test (your next method, i.e. the dependent one testCase2)

13) @AfterMethod

14) **@AfterClass** (it gets executed in the end)

... and so on.

Hence, it is clear that TestNG will NOT execute `@AfterClass` method directly after your test (testCase1) fails the first time, unless and until your test method is the only method present in your class. (Which is not the case since you have testCase2 in the same class). Now, you have two options where you can place your flush() method -

1) In your retry method inside the RetryAnalyzer implementation

2) In your `@AfterMethod`, but you need to check the status of result of the executed method because you probably want to execute it only if the test case fails, something like this -

```
@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void myAfterMethod(ITestResult testResult)
{
if(testResult.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE)
        {
            failed_count++;  
            //flush();
        }
}
```

**But what about the execution of dependent test cases?**

Test cases which are dependent on a failed test case, will be skipped by TestNG. Bonus point, if you want any test method to be executed anyway even if the test method on which it was dependent on failed, use `alwaysRun = true`. Ex -

```
    @Test(dependsOnMethods = { "test1" }, enabled = true, alwaysRun = true)
    public void test2()
    {
        //this will be executed even if test1 fails
    }
```

Comment: That would help in creation of data. But what about the execution of dependent test cases?

Comment: Its the opposite way Shivam. Since test case 2 is dependent on test case1, anytime the testcase2 fails; the @BeforeClass method should be executed followed by testcase1

Comment: No. There is no way tescase1 should execute after testcase2, let alone if testcase2 fails. That's exactly what dependency means. If testcase2 is dependent on testcase1, testcase1 should ALWAYS execute before testcase2.

Comment: Coming to @BeforeClass, it would be already executed before tescase1 and testcase2. Please read https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_execution_procedure.htm and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_dependency_test.htm to understand TestNG execution order.